# Create AppInsights from PowerShell with a pricing tier

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to create a new Application Insights resource using `New-AzureRmResource`. It appears that with [PR #979](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/pull/979/) one can use the `-SkuObject` parameter, but it isn't working for me and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
New-AzureRmResource -ResourceName "Testing"
    -ResourceGroupName "testing-group"
    -ResourceType "Microsoft.Insights/Components"
    -Location "Central US"
    -PropertyObject @{"Application_Type"="ASP.NET" }
    -SkuObject @{"Name"="Standard"}
    -Force
```

I've tried `"S"` and `"S0"` as the names, as well.

I have the PowerShell Azure module 1.0.2 installed, which may not have the `-SkuObject` parameter available yet. If that's the case, is there any way to specify the pricing tier through PowerShell?

Edit: I've also tried dropping the `-SkuObject` parameters and instead specifying it in the `PropertyObject`, but adding `"sku"="Standard"` (or `"S"` or `"S0"`) don't change the outcome. (The resources are always created in the Free tier.) The schema and templates have a few clues, but they seem to point to `sku`.

Comment: You will need to set it via the `PropertyObject` You'll need to look through the [schema](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas) to find the syntax (or the [templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates))

Comment: I've just had a look at [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com) for a Standard insights setup, and there isn't any where that it is configured, it also doesn't appear in the templates (apart from some cryptic [change log](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/commit/fa0aefc4ebeefae8fe4f38a29f7ccd923680e0dc) about it being removed) - you should try upgrading to 1.0.4, see if it makes any difference, but I don't think it is available via PropertyObject

Comment: Yeah, I saw that change about it being removed as well. Thanks for the info, I didn't realize 1.0.4 was out. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I'm not sure it helps much, but [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/dev/src/ResourceManager/Resources/Commands.ResourceManager/Cmdlets/Entities/Resources/ResourceSku.cs) is the class that says what is expected in the hashtable for -SkuObject - and it was put into the source in sept 15, so well before 1.0.2 was released. - and looking at the [tests](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/dev/src/ResourceManager/Resources/Commands.Resources.Test/ScenarioTests/ResourceTests.ps1) this is being used in SQL server deployments

Comment: Yeah, that was one of the classes included in the PR that I mentioned, but it's entirely possible it only works for SQL Server resources. /shrug

Reading the GitHub issues list, it looks like [there are plans](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/859) to implement the "sku" concept generically. I'll be patient. :)

Comment: I have thought for a while now, that if we just come back in about five years, Azure will be fantastic, with whole, accessible and documented APIs and stuff that works end to end that we don't need whole rolls of duck tape to strap together and make work. (OK, I admit, the documented part is clearly a pipe dream)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the latest ARM template schema for **`Microsoft.Insights/components`**, **`"sku"`** is not a valid property for it.

The "sku" property is only valid for the **`Microsoft.Web/serverfarms`** resource.

Ref: [azure-resource-manager-schemas/schemas/2014-04-01/Microsoft.Insights.json](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2014-04-01/Microsoft.Insights.json)

```
"components": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "Microsoft.Insights/components"
          ]
        },
        "apiVersion": {
          "enum": [
            "2014-04-01"
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "applicationId": {
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 1,
              "description": "Microsoft.Insights/components: applicationId"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "type",
        "apiVersion",
        "properties",
        "location"
      ],
      "description": "Microsoft.Insights/components"
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about either setting the tier or the usage of `SkuObject` flag for `New-AzureRmResource`

Comment: The point I want to highlight in my answer is there is no point to use SkuObject flag for the Insights component resource type because it is invalid based on it s schema. Sku is only valid for serverFarm resource type.

Comment: and if you look through the [commit log](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/commit/fa0aefc4ebeefae8fe4f38a29f7ccd923680e0dc) Sku was also removed from a number of other resource templates, including Microsoft.Sql yet that is used in the [test scenario](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/dev/src/ResourceManager/Resources/Commands.Resources.Test/ScenarioTests/ResourceTests.ps1) - this appears to be a parameter that doesn't follow the resource management schema (in the Azure undocumented fashion)